# dynamically write image's alt value as text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dynamic, alt

Trying to write a small function that updates a `paragraph` with an image's alt text. the `.active` class is the image being viewed. I'll launch this function on `doc.ready` and under a few `.click` events. Here's what i've got with no results:

```
$("#title").text($('.z.active').attr('alt', ''));
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the .attr('alt', '') part is setting an attribute - it looks/sounds like you're trying to get an attribute, correct?

Comment: Passing a second parameter to attr() sets the value. Use a single parameter (attribute name) to get the attribute value.

Comment: You are setting the alt value to an empty string.
Get the alt obj like this $('.z.active').attr('alt')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This illustrates the basics of the jQuery in question.  I assume you can handle the click events.

HTML:

```
<div class="z">
<img class="active" alt="foobar" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>
<div id="title"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#title").text($('.z .active').attr('alt'));
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNn6z/2/).